# Amadeus Node SDK | AuthenticationError 401 invalid access token

Tags: node.js, api, error-handling, amadeus

I'm completely new to amadeus API. I write a testing next.js app in order to learn it. It seems that I do everything according to the documentation on their [GitHub](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-node). But instead of a response, I get an authentication error 401 with "Invalid access token" title. I am sure the credentials I am posting are correct, I specifically checked this through the `console.log`. And I'm sure I copied them correctly from the application info on "amadeus for developers" website. Also if I make a request via curl as shown [here](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/authorization-262), I receive the token as expected. What else could be the problem?

Here is my code:

```
import Amadeus from 'amadeus';

const { CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET } = process.env;

const amadeus = new Amadeus({
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
});

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  let offersData = {};
  try {
    offersData = await amadeus.shopping.hotelOffers.get({
      cityCode: 'LON',
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('error:', e);
  }

  res.status(200).json(offersData);
};

export default handler;
```

and here is an error:

```
error: AuthenticationError {
  response: Response {
    headers: {
      date: 'Mon, 08 Nov 2021 12:26:51 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/vnd.amadeus+json',
      'content-length': '387',
      connection: 'close',
      'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="null",error="invalid_token",error_description="keymanagement.service.InvalidAPICallAsNoApiProductMatchFound: Invalid API call as no apiproduct match found"',
      'ama-gateway-request-id': 'rrt-094a25a712c8791ce-a-de-31141-46438978-1',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'origin, x-requested-with, accept, Content-Type, Authorization',
      'access-control-max-age': '3628800',
      'access-control-allow-methods': '*',
      server: 'Amadeus',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*'
    },
    statusCode: 401,
    request: Request {
      host: 'test.api.amadeus.com',
      port: 443,
      ssl: true,
      scheme: 'https',
      verb: 'GET',
      path: '/v2/shopping/hotel-offers',
      params: [Object],
      queryPath: '/v2/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=LON',
      bearerToken: 'ooJMMYLiK2B26hDyylrF0WWRKgZa',
      clientVersion: '5.7.0',
      languageVersion: '16.4.0',
      appId: null,
      appVersion: null,
      headers: [Object]
    },
    body: '\n' +
      '            {\n' +
      '                "errors": [\n' +
      '                        {\n' +
      '                            "code": 38190,\n' +
      '                            "title": "Invalid access token",\n' +
      '                            "detail": "The access token provided in the Authorization header is invalid",\n' +
      '                            "status": 401\n' +
      '                        }\n' +
      '                ]\n' +
      '            }\n' +
      '        ',
    result: { errors: [Array] },
    data: undefined,
    parsed: true
  },
  description: [
    {
      code: 38190,
      title: 'Invalid access token',
      detail: 'The access token provided in the Authorization header is invalid',
      status: 401
    }
  ],
  code: 'AuthenticationError'
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: UPD: I tried to make a postman request for flight offers with the bearer token that I received and everything worked well. But when I try to make a request for hotel offers I still get the same error. So the problem is with a certain endpoint. But I do everything as described in the documentation for this endpoint and, in theory, there should be no problems.
https://amadeus4dev.github.io/amadeus-node/#hoteloffers

Comment: Indeed there is an access issue with the Hotel Search v2 and the technical team is working on providing a solution.